# How to extract text in html table

Tags: php, html

I realized a code that through a button pressure allow to generate html table:

```
function crea_tabella($colonne,$suddivisione,$righe)
{
    $dipendenti = 0;
    $progressivo = 0;
    echo "<table border='1' width='50%' height='25%'>";

        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td></td>";
            echo "<td>Lunedì</td>";
            echo "<td>Martedì</td>";
            echo "<td>Mercoledì</td>";
            echo "<td>Giovedì</td>";
            echo "<td>Venerdì</td>";
            echo "<td>Sabato</td>";
        echo "</tr>";

        for($i=0; $i<$righe; $i++)
        {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td ><input name='casella $progressivo' type='text' value='Operaio $i' disabled='true'></td>";
            $progressivo++;
            for($j=0; $j<$colonne;$j++)
            {
                if($suddivisione == 1)
                {   
                    echo "<td><input type='text name='dipendente''></td>";
                }
                elseif($suddivisione == 2)
                {    
                    echo "<td>AM<input type='text' name='dipendente'><br>";
                    echo "       PM<input type='text name='dipdenente''></td>";
                }
            }
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table><br>";
}
```

Now I want to create another function that extract the content of a specific cell of the generated table..
see the red box: 
[image](http://forum.mrwebmaster.it/attachments/php/2511d1423578732-estrarre-codice-tabella-html-celle-prelevare.jpg)

how can do this?

**Example**

Operaio 1 : a b c d e f 
a b c d e f, is the content of the line Operaio 1

Comment: You ask for a specific cell, but then your image shows basically every cell being selected...which one is it?

Comment: Yeah! Those are the specific cells. As you can see in the first column "Operaio" I do not want to get the values contained in it. More specifically for "Operaio 1" I will have their 6 values ..

Comment: `type='text name='dipendente''` first you should fix this up to be `type='text' name='dipendente'` next you should give each cell a different name like `type='text' name='dipendente[1][1]'`, `type='text' name='dipendente[1][2]'` ... `type='text' name='dipendente[$row][$col]'` finally you should tell us if you want to get the contents by posting to another page `$_POST['dipendente'][1][2]` or as a javascript while they're on the page `document.getElementsByName("dipendente[1][2]")[0]`

Comment: There are many ways of traversing the DOM, but what matters is the desired output. How do you want to store the values...in a giant array or what?

Comment: I want do this on the same page, thanks for the other fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use either forms or javascript/jquery to do this. heres an example using jquery. the main functions i used were `.click()` to trigger the collecction of values on button click, `.each()` to cycle through the specified inputs, and `classes` to specify the inputs i want.  `.append()` was used to output the results

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.get').on('click', function(e) {
        var values = [];
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.getValue').each(function() {
            values.push($(this).val());
        });
        $('.results').html('');
        for(var i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
            $('.results').append('<br/>' + values[i]);
        }
    });
});
```

```css
td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Header 1</th>
            <th>Header 2</th>
            <th>Header 3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Left Column1</td>
            <td><input class="getValue" type="text" value="1,1"/></td>
            <td><input class="getValue" type="text" value="1,2"/></td>
            <td><input class="getValue" type="text" value="1,3"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Left Column2</td>
            <td><input class="getValue" type="text" value="2,1"/></td>
            <td><input class="getValue" type="text" value="2,2"/></td>
            <td><input class="getValue" type="text" value="2,3"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Left Column3</td>
            <td><input class="getValue" type="text" value="3,1"/></td>
            <td><input class="getValue" type="text" value="3,2"/></td>
            <td><input class="getValue" type="text" value="3,3"/></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<br/>
<br/>
<a href="#" class="get">Get Values of Inputs</a><br/>
<div class="results"></div>
```

EDIT: its easier to show code here. concerning your pastebin:

```
if($suddivisione == 1)
{      
    echo "<td><input type='text name='dipendente''></td>";
}
elseif($suddivisione == 2)
{        
    echo "<td>AM<input type='text' name='dipendente'><br>";
    echo "PM<input type='text name='dipdenente''></td>";
}
```

is incorrect, you have to use `dipendente` as a `class`, not a `name`. and also you have a bunch of typos... and your `'` quotes dont match up....

something like this:

```
if($suddivisione == 1)
{      
    echo "<td><input type='text class='dipendente'></td>";
}
elseif($suddivisione == 2)
{        
    echo "<td>AM<input type='text' class='dipendente'><br>";
    echo "PM<input type='text' class='dipendente'></td>";
}
```

if anything else isnt working, in your code, i'd bet its just typos (mispellings, not aligning quotes correctly) in your code.

Comment: Just one question: What change in the link again? instead of #

Comment: @HaroldFinch oh, im just using the `<a>` as a button that triggers the gathering of the `input` information. the `#` is just a placeholder in this case. does this example do what you want?

Comment: Because your code working, but if I implement your solution the value isn't appears. Check the complete class: http://pastebin.com/bEqcQpLv

Comment: @HaroldFinch, see my edit above. be careful about your typos. i didnt look through everything, just where the issue was.

Comment: I using your hint for fix, but it don't work if I press the anchor tag.

Comment: @HaroldFinch what's it saying in your console.

Comment: @HaroldFinch im sorry then, i cant help you further without seeing a demo of your code.  but i know this code is sound and is functional as shown in the example above and that its a way of implementing what you desire.

Comment: @HaroldFinch, i understand thats the complete code, but its not a demo. i do not currently have access to php friendly sandbox, so i cannot use that php code. so yes, i can see your code, but i cant demo your code.